# Adding .bson collection in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper, bson

*Hi! Long time lurker, first time asking a question.*

#### The Question

- Rails4 app + MongoDB with MongoMapper, working fine
- Currently only have a **Users** model with authentication working fine
- A co-worker passes me 2 other collections via Dropbox/Google Drive that I'll need to play with (e.g. **Cogs** & **Sprockets**) in my Rails app but these are just `cogs.bson` and `sprockets.bson`

I'm a bit new to Mongo... how do I incorporate these seeded collections into my MongoMapper ORM so that I have a model such as `Sprockets.rb` or `Cogs.rb` sitting my Models folder, able to manipulate the data in those .bson's? I'm assuming there's a `db.connect()` like feature for this but now I'm currently at a loss (yes, I've gone through the MongoMapper docs and even [asked Nunemaker on Twitter](https://twitter.com/jay_akers/status/571034569924861953)).

Any help would be appreciated :D Thanks

Comment: How did your coworker produce the `.bson`? I'm assuming using [`mongodump`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/), in which case you should use [`mongorestore`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#bin.mongorestore) to restore the data to a MongoDB instance. It's just MongoDB data, with no defined schema or model for MongoMapper. You'll need to write those bits yourself based on either what you can infer the schema to be from looking at the data, or ask your coworker to hand over his models as well as the raw data.

Comment: `mongodump` is the way they generated the `.bson`.

Recommendations regarding: *You'll need to write these bits*?
Sorry, I'm a bit new to Mongo. I'm just not sure how to go about writing this unless its in my `db/seeds.rb` file? `mongorestore` seems to be the way to go about but I'm not sure how that process goes

Answer (score 0):

So... what I went with is using the [Mongo Ruby Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver).

More bare bones but I'm able to find solutions to my problems.

Consider this closed.